# Socket/Interface filter Ioctl callback not getting called

Tags: macos, networking, kernel, kernel-extension

I have a small C program that does the following:

```
 int fd;
 fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

 ioctl(fd, ..., ...);

 close(fd);
```

My kext `ioctl` callback looks as follows:

```
errno_t
Router::Ioctl(void *cookie, socket_t so, unsigned long request, const char* argp)
{
    IOLog("-- SOCK IOCTL Request is %lu\n", request);
    return KERN_SUCCESS;
}
```

When I open a web page in Safari and stuff, I can see the output in the Console application

> default   16:09:08.557920 +0200   kernel  -- IOCTL Request is 2147772030

But when I execute my C program, it seems like it 'skips' my kext and nothing is printed.

Ideas on why this happens?

**EDIT**

Just for the sake of it, I also tried doing the same with an Interface filter - same result

Answer (score 1):

Not a conclusive answer as such, as your sample code is extremely vague and incomplete. A few suggestions and extra information that might help diagnose this:

1. What does your `sflt_register()` call look like? Your socket is a datagram (UDP) socket, but Safari is probably using a stream (TCP) socket. Socket filters are for one type of socket.
2. What `ioctl` are you performing in your test program? (Are you aware that custom ioctls on sockets are not supported?)
3. Do you see other (non-ioctl) socket events in your filter?
4. What were you expecting in the interface filter? Ioctls to a socket don't propagate to the interface.
5. Finally, be aware that NKEs are effectively deprecated. If you will likely need NKE functionality over the next few macOS releases, you need to get in touch with Apple. (Radar enhancement request and/or DTS)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. By deprecated you mean I won't be able to load them at all?

Comment: @Shai Apple announced at WWDC 2017 [Session 707](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/707/) that they were planning to remove NKEs eventually. (Generally, they seem to be trying to remove third party kernel access altogether in the long term.) I don't think the KPI going away in the next 2-3 or so major macOS releases (NB: I have no inside information), so it's still OK to build software on those KPIs if there is no alternative. However, you should notify Apple of how you're using them in your product, because you will need them to provide an alternative before NKEs are gone.

Comment: from what i've read, NE do not include the socket filter functionality NKEs have. my NKE performs bind/connect manipulations - is that even possible with NE?

Comment: No, as far as I'm aware, that's currently not possible in user space. This is exactly the kind of thing Apple wants to hear about - what you're using NKEs for, and what kind of functionality you'd require from a user space replacement. (I suggest you watch the video or read the transcript.)